# MySQL - include a default value in LOAD XML INFILE statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, xml

I have the follwing table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DEFAULT` VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITEM` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SURNAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOADED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I then have an XML file containing multiple entries such as:

```
<RECORD
  ITEM="item1"
  TIMESTAMP="2015-08-26 10:04:40"
  NAME="Bob"
  SURNAME="SMITH"
/>
```

I use MySQL to import the data with:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'c:/myFile.xml'
INTO TABLE `test`.`tab1`
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<RECORD>';
```

This works OK. However I need to specify a Default value for the `DEFAULT` field. But it needs to be specified at the time I load the file, and will be different for each file.
(for the sake of argument let's use the filename, `myfile.xml`)

How can I add a default value for this row during the XML Import?

I looked at using something like:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'c:/myFile.xml'
INTO TABLE `test`.`tab1` (@default="myfile.xml")
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<RECORD>'; 
SET DEFAULT=@default;
```

But it didn't like that. Is there a way round this?

Comment: Can this not be built into the logic of whatever creates the xml file?

Comment: unfortunately not. It's an external product, over which I have no control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one needs to do something more complex that is available in the syntax, it is often useful to 'stage' the data through a temp table:

Perhaps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp ( ... DEFAULT 'myfile' ... );
LOAD XML ...;
INSERT INTO tab1 SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

or:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE tab1;
LOAD XML ...;
UPDATE tmp SET DEFAULT = 'myfile';
INSERT INTO tab1 SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Comment: cheers, that's pretty much what I was thinking. I was just wondering if there was a simpler way, I guess not.